# Why do functions need to be declared before they are used?

Tags: c++, function-declaration

When reading through some answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration), I started wondering why the compiler actually *does* need to know about a function when it first encounters it. Wouldn't it be simple to just add an extra pass when parsing a compilation unit that collects all symbols declared within, so that the order in which they are declared and used does not matter anymore?

One could argue, that declaring functions before they are used certainly is good style, but I am wondering, is there are any other reason why this is mandatory in C++?

**Edit - An example to illustrate:** Suppose you have to functions that are defined inline in a header file. These two function call each other (maybe a recursive tree traversal, where odd and even layers of the tree are handled differently). The only way to resolve this would be to make a forward declaration of one of the functions before the other.

A more common example (though with classes, not functions) is the case of classes with `private` constructors and factories. The factory needs to know the class in order to create instances of it, and the class needs to know the factory for the `friend` declaration.

If this is requirement is from the olden days, why was it not removed at some point? It would not break existing code, would it?

Comment: Actually even in the actual C++ you can find areas where a function can used before it is declared (to be strict in the wordings, "before"  is about the order the program source is read) -- inside a class! (That's probably explained by that a function definition is put by the compiler behind the class declaration, as pointed out by someone here.)
class A {
public:
  static void foo(void) {
    bar();
  }
private:
  static void bar(void) {
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  A::foo();
  return 0;
}

Comment: Many answers point out that this is a heritage from C, whose compiler worked in a single pass because computers were slow and memory was tight. What I'm missing in all the answers is: now that computers are fast and memory is plenty, why hasn't two-pass compilation been added to the C++ language? Is there a fundamental reason why it would break backwards compatibility with older C++ programs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How do you propose to resolve ***undeclared*** identifiers that are ***defined in a different translation unit***?

C++ has no module concept, but has separate translation as an inheritance from C. A C++ compiler will compile each translation unit by itself, not knowing anything about other translation units at all. (Except that `export` broke this, which is probably why it, sadly, never took off.)
***Header files***, which is where you usually put declarations of identifiers which are defined in other translation units, actually are just a very clumsy way of slipping the same declarations into different translation units. They will not make the compiler aware of there being other translation units with identifiers being defined in them.

***Edit*** re your additional examples:
With all the textual inclusion instead of a proper module concept, compilation already takes agonizingly long for C++, so requiring another compilation pass (where compilation already is split into several passes, not all of which can be optimized and merged, IIRC) would worsen an already bad problem. And changing this would probably alter overload resolution in some scenarios and thus break existing code.

Note that C++ does require an additional pass for parsing class definitions, since member functions defined inline in the class definition are parsed as if they were defined right *behind* the class definition. However, this was decided when C with Classes was thought up, so there was no existing code base to break.

Comment: Not all language split the compilation in multiple translation unit. Take for exemple Java (there are other language that do it) where the compiler can find all the other required files, and parse them to get all the exported entities.

Comment: @Sylvian: Um, I thought this only had a `c++` tag? Anyway, I don't know Java, but C#, which _has_ a module concept, does __not__ require you to _declare_ your functions. You just define them in one module, refer to this module in another one, and the compiler will pick up the identifiers while compiling that other module.

Comment: @sbi I was trying to say that C++ could have been designed with a module system. That would have allowed to split the code in multiple files without requiring forward-declaration, and would not have implied more resource consomption from the compiler (it could have been more efficient than .h / .cpp separation). So having separate compilation unit could not have been the only reason for imposing forward-declaration.

Comment: @Sylvian: Ah, I see. I had already tried to address this in my edit.

Comment: @sbi: I added an example that illustrates a point that has nothing to do with declaring identifiers in other compilation units.

Comment: I don't see how the issue of translation units/modules can be putting limits on the order of declarations and uses. You don't give an explicit answer to the question! In your "answer", you don't discuss at all what would go wrong (**in the C++ language design** or compiler implementation) if a declaration of a thing appeared after the thing is used (simply inside one translation unit).

Comment: C++20 added modules, but you still need to declare functions before you can use them.

Answer (score 10):

Historically C89 let you do this. The first time the compiler saw a use of a function and it didn't have a predefined prototype, it "created" a prototype that matched the use of the function.

When C++ decided to add strict typechecking to the compiler, it was decided that prototypes were now required. Also, C++ inherited the single-pass compilation from C, so it couldn't add a second pass to resolved all symbols.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Even C99 removed support for implicit declarations of functions, and for a good reason. It's so easy to spend hours wondering why a program crashes only to find out that you merely forgot to include a header, so that the compiler silently implicitly declared functions with wrong prototypes.

Comment: Single-pass compilation? So how does it deal with classes?

Answer (score 9):

Because C and C++ are *old* languages. Early compilers didn't have a lot of memory, so these languages were designed so a compiler can just read the file from top to bottom, without having to consider the file *as a whole*.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how this would decrease memory usage in a significant way. At the point when compiler reaches the end of file, it stores all definitions in memory; just like it would without the requirement for declaration before use.
A more probable reason would be to improve compilation time by removing the need for extra pass. However, this is more relevant for C. C++ has classes which require extra pass anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I think of two reasons:

- It makes the parsing easy. No extra pass needed.
- It also defines *scope*; symbols/names are *available* **only after** its declaration. Means, if I declare a global variable `int g_count;`, the later code after this line can use it, but not the code before the line! Same argument for global functions.

As an example, consider this code:

```
void g(double)
{
    cout << "void g(double)" << endl;
}
void f()
{
    g(int());//this calls g(double) - because that is what is visible here
}
void g(int)
{
    cout << "void g(int)" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    f();
    g(int());//calls g(int) - because that is what is the best match!
}
```

Output:

> void g(double)
>   void g(int)

See the output at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/EsK4A

Comment: If you declare a global variable, you get what you ask for.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason will be to make the compilation process as efficient as possible. If you add an extra pass you're adding both time and storage. Remember that C++ was developed back before the time of Quad Core Processors :)

Answer (score 2):

The C programming language was designed so that the compiler could be implemented as a [one-pass compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler). In such a compiler, each compilation phase is only executed once. In such a compiler you cannot referrer to an entity that is defined later in the source file.

Moreover, in C, the compiler only interpret a single compilation unit (generally a .c file and all the included .h files) at a time. So you needed a mechanism to referrer to a function defined in another compilation unit.

The decision to allow one-pass compiler and to be able to split a project in small compilation unit was taken because at the time the memory and the processing power available was really tight. And allowing forward-declaration could easily solve the issue with a single feature.

The C++ language was derived from C and inherited the feature from it (as it wanted to be as compatible with C as possible to ease the transition).

Answer (score 1):

I guess because C is quite old and at the time C was designed efficient compilation was a problem because CPUs were much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ is a static language, the compiler needs to check if values' type is compatible with the type expected in the function's parameters. Of course, if you don't know the function signature, you can't do this kind of checks, thus defying the purpose of a static compiler. But, since you have a silver badge in C++, I think you already know this.

The C++ language specs were made right because the designer didn't want to force a multi-pass compiler, when hardware was not as fast as the one available today. In the end, I think that, if C++ was designed today, this imposition would go away but then, we would have another language :-).

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest reasons why this was made mandatory even in C99 (compared to C89, where you could have implicitly-declared functions) is that implicit declarations are very error-prone. Consider the following code:

First file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void doSomething(double x, double y)
{
    printf("%g %g\n",x,y);
}
```

Second file:

```
int main()
{
    doSomething(12345,67890);
    return 0;
}
```

This program is a syntactically valid* C89 program. You can compile it with GCC using this command (assuming the source files are named `test.c` and `test0.c`):

```
gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors test.c test0.c -o test
```

Why does it print something strange (at least on linux-x86 and linux-amd64)? Can you spot the problem in the code at a glance? Now try replacing `c89` with `c99` in the command line — and you'll be immediately notified about your mistake by the compiler.

Same with C++. But in C++ there're actually other important reasons why function declarations are needed, they are discussed in other answers.

<sub>* But has undefined behavior</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Still, you can have a use of a function before it is declared sometimes (to be strict in the wording: "before" is about the order in which the program source is read) -- inside a class!:

```
class A {
public:
  static void foo(void) {
    bar();
  }
private:
  static void bar(void) {
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  A::foo();
  return 0;
}
```

(Changing the class to a namespace doesn't work, per my tests.)

That's probably because the compiler actually puts the member-function definitions from inside the class right after the class declaration, as someone has pointed it out here in the answers.

The same approach could be applied to the whole source file: first, drop everything but declaration, then handle everything postponed. (Either a two-pass compiler, or large enough memory to hold the postponed source code.)

Haha! So, they thought **a whole source file would be too large** to hold in the memory, **but a single class with function definitions wouldn't**: they can allow for a whole class to sit in the memory and wait until the declaration is filtered out (or do a 2nd pass for the source code of classes)!

Answer (score -1):

I remember with Unix and Linux, you have `Global` and `Local`. Within your own environment local works for functions, but does not work for `Global(system)`. You must declare the function `Global`.