# C++ - struct errors

Tags: c++, struct

Following an example at: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/47-structs/ relating to **structs**, and when I tried to compile this program:

```
#include <iostream>
void PrintInformation(Employee sEmployee)
{
std::cout<<"ID: "<<sEmployee.nID<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Age: "<<sEmployee.nAge<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Wage: "<<sEmployee.fWage<<std::endl;
}

struct Employee {int nID;int nAge;float fWage;};

int main()
{
Employee abc;
abc.nID=123;
abc.nAge=27;
abc.fWage=400;
// print abc's information
PrintInformation(abc);
return 0;
}
```

I get the following:

[image]

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: see this topic [Why do functions need to be declared before they are used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757705/why-do-functions-need-to-be-declared-before-they-are-used)

Comment: @Nawaz. Thanks for directing me to the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare the struct *before* the function that attempts to use it.

C (and by extension, C++) were designed for "single-pass" compilation.  Therefore, everything must be available to the compiler by the time it's required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you just describe this term: "single-pass" compilation? Thanks.