# declaration error when compiling code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>




int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int one = atoi(argv[1]);
    int two = atoi(argv[2]);
    int finally;
    finally = func(one,two);
    printf("%d",finally);
    return 0;


}


int func(int first,int second) {
    int counter = 0;
    int new = first;
    while (counter != second)
        new = new*first;
        counter += 1;
    return new;

}
```

Im very new to coding so a lot of this might look like nonsense,
So this code is a complicated way of using the power arithmetic operation,5*3 == 125,
so if i type (./a.out 5 3) it should give out 125,
i seem to get this error

```
extension.c:15:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'func' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        finally = func(one,two);
              ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do functions need to be declared before they are used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757705/why-do-functions-need-to-be-declared-before-they-are-used)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: implicit declaration of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function)

Answer (score 1):

Move the function declaration before the main() function / or alternatively leave it where it is and simply add a function prototype before the main().

Comment: new is not a keyword. new is a keyword in some other languages that aren't C.

Comment: i changed both or those,the function now complies but it still doesn't do what i wanted it to do?

Comment: @Charana that's because of a completely different problem you have.

Comment: @immibis indeed you're right, I got mixed up between languages