# Declaration of function in c++

Tags: c++, function, raspberry-pi, declaration

I wrote this code and I don't know what to do to change that. This code I want to use in my Raspberry pi with sonars - hc sr 04 to measure a distance. Please do you know how to fix my code? :) before this I wrote a code for-example. This is my real code. So please check it again :) thanks!

```
int zmeratSonar1() {
int smer = 0;
printf("meram sonar1");
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar1, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar1, LOW);

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar1)==LOW);
long zaciatok = micros();

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar1)==HIGH);
long cas = micros() - zaciatok;

int vzdialenost = cas/58;

if(vzdialenost < 100) {
    smer = zmeratSonar28();  // <----here is my problem
}
else if(vzdialenost > 100) {
    zmeratSonar1();
}

return smer;
}

int zmeratSonar28(){
int smer = 0;
printf("meram sonare 2 a 8");
//------------SONAR 2---------------------
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar2, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar2, LOW);

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar2)==LOW);
long startTime2 = micros();

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar2)==HIGH);
long travelTime2 = micros() - startTime2;

int distance2 = travelTime2/58;

//------------SONAR 8----------------------
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar8, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(20);
digitalWrite(TRIGsonar8, LOW);

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar8)==LOW);
long startTime8 = micros();

while (digitalRead(ECHOsonar8)==HIGH);
long travelTime8 = micros() - startTime8;

int distance8 = travelTime8/58;

//porovnanie vzdialenosti
if(distance2 > 100 || distance8 > 100) {
    if(distance2 > distance8) {
        smer = 2;
    }

    else {
        smer = 8;
    }
}

else{
    smer = 0;
}

return smer;
}
```

Comment: When doing a comparison, use `==`, as a single `=` is an assignment operator. It should be: `if(i % 2 == 1)`. Also, you probably need a semicolon at the end of the second line: `int number = 0;`

Comment: @Timco You wrote three sentences that didn't deliver any useful information as to what your problem is.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should describe what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, yes I know, sorry. I wrote it in a hurry....here is my real code

Comment: Post your error, please.

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function 'zmeratSonar28' -Wimplicit-function-declaration

but you don't know what is - zmeratSonar28 - because you can not see my code

Comment: @SwiftArchitect please check my code above, I have edited it, now it is my real code :)

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not C? implicit function declaration is a warning in C but an error in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code which will cause compiler errors:

If you're using the `sum()` function in `int a()`, then you need to forward-declare it.

```
int sum();

int add() {
    //
}

int sum() {
    //
}
```

All `sum()` really does however, is add 100 to a variable. This can be incorporated into the `add()` function very easily via the `+=` operator, meaning your code is equivalent to this:

```
int a() {
    int number = 0;        //Added a necessary ';'
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
        if(i % 2 == 1) {   //Corrected this from if(i % 2 = 1)
            number += 100; //No need for the sum() function
        }  
    }
    return number;
}
```

**The crucial aspect:**

There are a **lot** of additional optimizations you could perform on your setup; Essentially, `int a()` could be simplified to

```
int a() {
    return 1000;
}
```

So, you could just as easily *not* have `a()` be a function at all:

```
#define a() 1000
```

Or, (probably better):

```
const int a = 1000;
```

**EDIT :** 
For your updated code you need to write `int zmeratSonar28();` before `int zmeratSonar1()` starts:

```
int zmeratSonar28();

int zmeratSonar1() {
    //Sonar code stuff
}

int zmeratSonar28() {
    //Other sonar code stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the function `sum` before you have declared it. You could either move the function sum above the use, or you could forward declare it:

```
int sum();  // Forward declared
int number = 0;

int a() {
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  if((i % 2) == 1) {
   number = sum();
  }  
 }
 return number;
}

int sum() {
 number = number + 100;
 return number;
}
```

Further explanation of the this problem, can be found elsewhere on Stack Overflow, such as the answers to this question: [Why do functions need to be declared before they are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757817/111143)

Note: I never thoroughly tested your code, which I guess you never did either, so as LogicStuff pointed out it didn't even compile, I've made a few changes to make the code compile, as few changes as possible so that the original code should still be visible from it. Thanks for pointing it out LogicStuff.

Comment: You choose the lazy, global variable way, then :)

Comment: @LogicStuff not the most pretty solution, but I really wanted the function signature to be the same as the OP's :)

Comment: Hi, I wrote it in a hurry...if you want my real code, please write me your email :) :)

Comment: @TommyA please check my code above, I have edited it, now it is my real code :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your problem is that you have a compilation error. You use `sum` in place where it is not yet visible. Either move sum above a(), or forward declare it with `int sum();` above `a()`.

Another  problem is that:

```
if(i % 2 = 1) {
```

should be:

```
if((i % 2) == 1) {
           ^~~~~ !!
```

Whoo, I found third problem :)

You try to use variable `number` inside `int sum()` which is declared inside of `a()`, you simply cannot do it. You should pass number to sum by reference (no need for return value, you return it in number parameter):

```
void sum(int& number) {
```

and call it:

```
sum(number);  // this is in place of `number = sum();`
```

in `a()`

Comment: I propose changing the `sum` signature (and show OP the implementation), so it either just returns the new value, or modifies the argument. While doing both compiles with the implementation OP currently has, it's weird and it could all be as well just one `+=`.

Comment: @LogicStuff fixed it, each time I look at this code I find something new

Comment: Hi, I wrote it in a hurry...if you want my real code, please write me your email :) :)

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski please write me your email, I will send you my full real code :)

Comment: @TimcoVanco why dont you want to post your Full Real Code to SO?

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski Because it does not allow me to do that, I can not post new question for 7 days... :(

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski Check my code above, I have edited it :) now it is my real code